# WPML language tags (Qtranslate feature)

Tags: multi-language, translation, plugin-qtranslate, plugin-wpml

I for many years used qtranslate plugin for translating my wordpress websites, but for now I decided to use other plugin, called WPML.

And now I'm struggled with one problem:

I am missing one feature from qtranslate plugin, where with conditional language tags we have possibility simply translate plugins, like wp-pagenavi, Breadcrumb NavXT and etc..

These tags looks secondly:

```
<!–-:en–->English text<!–-:–-><!–-:de–->German text<!–-:–->
```

So, for example one standart field of wp-pagenavi plugin in admin area:

```
Page %CURRENT_PAGE% of %TOTAL_PAGES%
```

Modified:

```
<!–-:en–->Page<!–-:–-><!–-:de–->Seite<!–-:–-> %CURRENT_PAGE% <!–-:en–->of<!–-:–-><!–-:de–->von<!–-:–-> %TOTAL_PAGES%
```

Output in German language must be:

```
Seite %CURRENT_PAGE% von %TOTAL_PAGES%
```

So, I will be very thankful for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Use [WordPress i18n functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Normally good plugins are translation-ready, and you should create your translation files for that plugins (if not already present). Explain how to is too much for this answer, start looking at Codex page linked above, search Google and also have a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization).

If a plugin is not translation-ready use another plugin or modify it to be translation ready.

The plugins you mentioned (wp-pagenavi, Breadcrumb NavXT) are not only translation-ready but also already translated in different languages (german included), so if you have edited them, replace the original, and using WPML and they'll "magically" work without to do anything.

Comment: I can see only user interface translated for those plugins(different langs in admin), but when we are talking about custom fields, they stay still the same, no matter in what language I am browsing thru website.
Any ideas, or concrete code snippet (or instructions)? :)

Comment: Currently i am playing with http://wpml.org/documentation/support/translation-for-texts-by-other-plugins-and-themes/ feature, but with no luck... :(

Comment: This feature http://wpml.org/documentation/support/translation-for-texts-by-other-plugins-and-themes/ perhaps must be developed by plugin developer, so standart user can't do much.

Comment: You're probably missing something, as you can basically translate everything with WPML: custom fields, strings, taxonomies, taxonomy terms, custom posts, admin options, etc.